# I am getting an error to define again the scalar variable even when i have defined it in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have written the code as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST22]
    @database_name VARCHAR(200),
    /*Enter the Start Date and End date in the format MM/DD/YYYY*/
    @Start_Date VARCHAR(200),
    @End_Date VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @querystring VARCHAR(MAX)

   --JOINS THE VENDOR MASTER FILE WITH THE PAYMENTS FILE TO IDENTIFY VENDORS WHO DO 
   -- NOT APPEAR IN THE PAYMENTS FILE FOR THE GIVEN PERIOD OF ANALYSIS
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID('dummy1'))
       DROP TABLE  dummy1

   DECLARE @Test Nvarchar(50)
   SET @test =N'"Test1"'

   SET @querystring = 'select @test as Test1, getdate() as time1
                       into dbo.dummy1
                       from sys.tables'

   EXEC (@querystring)
END
```

and when I run this code I am getting the following error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@test".

Please suggest what the error is?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @querystring ='select @test as Test1, getdate() as time1
```

When this query is executing, it is executing as a standalone query, in which @test is not defined

```
EXEC (@querystring)
```

during this execution, the parameter @test must be defined.

In my opinion what you wish to achieve is

```
SET @querystring = 'select ' + @test + ' as Test1, getdate() as time1 ..... '
```

This concatenation will put the value of @test in the query and the new query will be

```
SELECT N'"Test1"' as Test1, getdate() as time1....
```

---

*Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if you found it helpful.*

Answer (score 0):

As @Manish [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23321502/15498), `@test` *isn't* defined within the scope of your [`EXEC`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) statement. However, a cleaner way to work with it than their proposal is to use `sp_executesql`:

```
SET @querystring = 'select @test as Test1, getdate() as time1
                   into dbo.dummy1
                   from sys.tables'

DECLARE @Parms nvarchar(max)
SET @Parms = N'@test nvarchar(50)'

EXEC sp_executesql @querystring,@Parms,@test
```

This keeps it as a separate parameter within the inner scope of the `EXEC` and so avoids any potential concerns about SQL Injection that arise whenever you concatenate SQL *code* and *data*.